# Does the 32-bit addressing limit (of a 32-bit application) include dedicated video memory?

Tags: 32-bit, ram, overlap, memory-address, video-card

**Can a 32-bit application utilize more than 4GB between system RAM and video RAM?**

Context: Some games (for instance, Skyrim) are compiled under 32-bit architectures. I am running a 64-bit system with 16GB of DDR3 on the motherboard and 4GB of GDDR5 on the graphics card. ***Does the 32-bit architecture of the program limit its address capability to 4GB of total space, or is the graphics memory (which is on-board the graphics card) in a separate address space, thus neatly allowing the total sum of addressable memory to be greater than 4GB?***

I ask because I have no way of knowing whether the paged amount in task manager and the amount of graphics memory used in GPU-Z are independent sets (which would seem to indicate that they are separately addressed, as the sum can be greater than 4GB), or if there is overlap between them.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matters in which the game is compilled. It depends on your OS architecture. As you are uing 64 bit it will utilise all the memory